# directories under /proc directory

Tags: proc

when I tried `$ ls /proc` ,I found a lot of `directories(numbered - for PID and other subdirectories...)` as follows :

I am describing only some of the numbered subdirectories,and other subdirectories

```
$ ls /proc
 129   1475  1899  2     21    2302 (PID's-correct me if i am wrong)
 acpi ,asound, bus,driver, fs, ipmi ,irq , mounts , net ,scsi ,self,sys, sysvipc,tty(other subdirecories ),
```

and when I tried `$ ls - l /proc` it displayed some `->` character in it :

```
$ ls -l /proc
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root       root                    11 Sep  7 17:06 mounts -> self/mounts 
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root       root                     8 Sep  7 17:06 net -> self/net
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root       root                     0 Sep  7  2014 self -> 4806
```

Here in `Access Specifier` full access is there`(lrwxrwxrwx)`,my question is:
what does `l` specify here in `lrwxrwxrwx`
what does these `->` character means? like in(`mounts -> self/mounts , net -> self/net,self -> 4806 etc.`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presence of `->` means that that "entry" in the directory is a symbolic link (symlink) to a file/directory somewhere else. In this case, `/proc/mounts` is a symlink to `/proc/self/mounts`.

Symlinks typically have a permission of 0777, since it isn't the one allowing/restricting access to a file/directory (hence, the `rwxrwxrwx`). However, whatever permissions are on the file/directory still do come into effect, so if a file has permissions `0600` or `rw-------`, then only the user owning the file can read or write into it, either directly or through a symlink.

I'm not entirely sure on the `l`, but my guess is that it's an indication that that entry is a symlink.

Comment: Thanx @saiarcot895 ,well as 0777 corresponds to symbolic link permission ,implies l = 0 ,and others are set(1's) so 7(owner)7(grup)7(rest world) ,isnt it?

Comment: Yes. Hence, the guess that the `l` is specially for symlinks.